# Distinct json object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using spring boot and I generated a json object.

```
[
    {"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"good","category":"AA"},
    {"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"bad","category":"BB"},
    {"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"poor","category":"CC"}

    {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"very bad","category":"AA"}
    {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"nice","category":"XX"}
    {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"okey","category":"YY"}
]
```

I have to distinct the **date** and get a new json object like following

```
[
    {"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340", "name":"abc", "feedback_1":"good", "feedback_2":"bad", "feedback_3":"poor", "category_1":"AA", "category_2":"BB", "category_3":"CC"},
    {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042", "name":"xyz", "feedback_1":"very bad", "feedback_2":"nice", "feedback_3":"poor", "category_1":"AA", "category_2":"XX", "category_3":"YY"}
]
```

I try to get this format in Java or JavaScript. I tried my best using online resources but I failed since I'm new to JavaScript, how can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have already tried...

Answer (score 0):

take 2 array

```
1st array={"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"good","category":"AA"},
{"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"bad","category":"BB"},
{"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"poor","category":"CC"}

2nd={"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"very bad","category":"AA"}
{"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"nice","category":"XX"}
{"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"okey","category":"YY"}
```

and use array_unique to get unique values

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to create an object and add counter to keep record of frequency of your JSON and using this counter add `feedback` and `category`. After that remove the counter from your result.

```js
var data = [ {"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"good","category":"AA"}, {"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"bad","category":"BB"}, {"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"poor","category":"CC"}, {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"very bad","category":"AA"}, {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"nice","category":"XX"}, {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"okey","category":"YY"} ];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
  var key = o.data + "|" + o.name;
  r[key] = r[key] || {date: o.date, name: o.name, count:1};
  r[key] = Object.assign({}, r[key], {['feedback_'+r[key].count] : o.feedback, ['category_'+r[key].count]: o.category, count : r[key].count+1});
  return r;
},{}));

result.forEach(o => delete o.count);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) library:

```js
var data = [{"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"good","category":"AA"}, {"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"bad","category":"BB"}, {"date":"2017-11-20T17:12:01.340","name":"abc","feedback":"poor","category":"CC"}, {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"very bad","category":"AA"}, {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"nice","category":"XX"}, {"date":"2017-12-15T16:53:02.042","name":"xyz","feedback":"okey","category":"YY"}];

var temp = Enumerable.From(data).GroupBy("$.date").Select("{date: $.Key(), name: $.First().name, feedback: Enumerable.From($).Select('$.feedback').ToArray(), category: Enumerable.From($).Select('$.category').ToArray() }").ToArray();

for (var item of temp) {
  for (var prop of ['feedback', 'category']) {
    for (var x of item[prop])
      item[prop + '_' + (item[prop].indexOf(x) + 1)] = x
    delete item[prop];
  }
}

console.log(temp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js"></script>
```